# Maven internal Repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus

I have internal nexus repository. I want to install plugins from internal repository, having the dependencies which I want to download from the central maven repository. I am new to maven and really struggling to do the required configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Once you deployed your own plugins into a nexus repository (say "releases") add that repository into the Nexus Group that contains both maven central and your releases repository. Usually developers will only use one url (mirror configured in settings.xml) from nexus and deploy artifacts into a specific repository.

In addition you need to make sure to add the maven group id of your plugins into settings.xml in the pluginGroups section: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups

That should already work.

Comment: Its not able to get the dependencies from the nexus repository as it is unable to locate the dependent jar files gives error like  The POM for com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0 is missing, no dependency information available for some other jar files as well

Comment: what version of nexus are you using and how does the settings.xml look?